# How to load yelp dump file in neo4j desktop?

Tags: neo4j, dump, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-browser, neo4j-desktop

I'm using Neo4j Desktop Version 1.4.3. I've created a new project named "Yelp Project", then uploaded the yelp dump file in it, but I'm not getting the option "Create new DBMS from dump". So I selected Add --> Local DBMS and created a database. But when I open Neo4j Browser, there are no nodes and relationships. I'm not able to figure out how to get this done, can someone help [refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWBkf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The feature that you are looking for is not yet available for Neo4j desktop Windows version. See below community thread discussion then scroll at the bottom.

> https://community.neo4j.com/t/missing-create-new-dbms-from-dump-yelp-dataset/29393